# SQL not working with ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, oracle, resultset

SQL is working fine in SQL developer but when I try to use it in ResultSet its throwing `Invalid Column Name` error, Code:

```
  String assignList = "SELECT table1.name , table1.spads , table1.group , table1.id , max(table2.date_) ,max(table2.event) "
                    + " FROM FOMOWNER_LSR.table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN   ( SELECT id, MAX(date_) AS latest FROM FOMOWNER_LSR.table2  GROUP BY id )  rev "
                    + " ON rev.id = table1.id LEFT OUTER JOIN FOMOWNER_LSR.table2  ON table2.id = rev.id "
                    + " AND table2.date_ = rev.latest group by table1.name , table1.spads , table1.group ,table1.id order by table1.id desc " ;


            PreparedStatement assignListStmt = null;
            Connection conn = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            // StringBuffer body = new StringBuffer();
            try {

                ArrayList<getssets> getset = new ArrayList<getssets>();
                //conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hw-dbt-rac.syniverse.com:1521/WLNPT", "utlapp100", "g0wlnp");
                System.out.println("before calling fomlsr DB connection");
                conn = DBConnector.getConnection();
                System.out.println("after calling fomlsr DB connection");
                if (conn == null)
                    throw new SQLException("NULL connection in GUIActionClass");
                if (conn.isClosed())
                    throw new SQLException("Connection is closed");
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                System.out.println("DB CONNECTION ESTABLISHED");
                assignListStmt = conn.prepareStatement(assignList);
                rs = assignListStmt.executeQuery();
                System.out.println("After the execute query");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    getssets guiAssign = new getssets();
                    guiAssign.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                    guiAssign.setspads(rs.getString("spads"));
                    guiAssign.setgroup(rs.getString("group"));
                    guiAssign.setId(rs.getString("id"));
                    guiAssign.setDate(rs.getTimestamp("date_"));
                    guiAssign.setEvent(rs.getString("event"));
                    getset.add(guiAssign);

                }
```

Another class file with setters and getters (getssets)

```
private String name;
    private String spads;
    private String group;
    private String id;
    private String date_;
    private String event;



public String getName() {
    return nullToEmpty(name);
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getspads() {
    return nullToEmpty(spads);
}
public void setspads(String spads) {
    this.spads = spads;
}
public String getgroup() {
    return nullToEmpty(group);
}
public void setgroup(String group) {
    this.group = group;
}
public String getId() {
    return nullToEmpty(id);
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getDate() {
    return nullToEmpty(date_);
}
public void setDate(String date_) {
    this.date_ = date_;
}
public String getEvent() {
    return nullToEmpty(event);
}
public void setEvent(String Event) {
    this.event = event;
}   
private String nullToEmpty(String st){
    if(st==null)
        st = "";
    return st;
```

My task is to print these values in GUI using JSP.

Below is the error I am getting in logs

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3291)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1914)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:1515)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl.getString(Unknown Source)
        at com.tsiconnections.fom.action.GUIActionClass.execute(GUIActionClass.java:83)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1480)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:506)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3750)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
<Aug 28, 2018 5:52:15 AM EDT> <Error> <com.tsiconnections.fom.action.GUIActionClass> <BEA-000000> <SQLException: Invalid column name>
com.tsiconnections.fom.exception.FilterServiceException
        at com.tsiconnections.fom.action.GUIActionClass.execute(GUIActionClass.java:96)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1480)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:506)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3750)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
<Aug 28, 2018 5:52:15 AM EDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@157132757[app:fomWebLSR module:fomWebLSR path:/fomWebLSR spec-version:null]] Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:441)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1480)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:506)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

A column with name "date_" is acceptable in SQL and Java?
Can I use string to get the date and times?
what else needs to be verified?

Comment: Let's start with the basic checks.  Does your raw SQL query execute on Oracle without any problem at all?

Comment: "Invalid Column Name" means that you're selecting a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: what is line GUIActionClass.java:83 in your class ?

Comment: This query is working fine in SQL developer .
Line-83 is " tpassignment.setDate(rs.getString("date_"));"

Comment: Please put some effort into stripping down your code sample to the bare minimum needed to make your point.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You column name should be consistent, change the last columns in SQL with aliases:

```
max(table2.date_) as date_ ,max(table2.event) as event
```

Comment: I think there are many other problems with the query and Java code.

Comment: Can you please help in identifying those

Comment: Hi, After making "max(table2.date_) as date_ ,max(table2.event) as event" this change ,I am not getting invalid column error and able to see the columns in GUI page.
But Event column is not populated still . Event column has comments like "last updated by xyz" and so on .

Comment: @chaatat aren't you missing `table1.event` in group by clause? should end with `,table1.event order by table1.id desc " ;`

Comment: Hi I am giving max(table1.event) , so dont have to include in group by claude. 
now this Event also worked . I did a mistake in the String upper and lower case .After changing all to lower case, it worked 
Thanks for your immediate help

Comment: Also, I still want to understand if there is any issue in java code? or SQL.
I am getting my required output  , but please suggest if any changes required 
again thanks everyone for your time

Comment: @chaatat See Java conventions for classes e.g. " Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized" in https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html also make sure you release your resources (conn, assignListStmt ,rs)